# Merging two paragraphs in itext to Single line

Tags: java, itext

I want to create a paragraph which contains text and an image.

```
Paragraph paraRevenue = new Paragraph();
Paragraph imagePara = new Paragraph();
Paragraph com = new Paragraph();
paraRevenue.add("text here");
imagePara.add(new Chunk(imgRevenue, 0, 0));
imagePara.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
com.add(paraRevenue);
com.add(imagePara);
```

Image should be right aligned.

My problem is that its coming in two different lines.
Is there any way I can display this in single line ?

Comment: Have you tried keeping both in sinlge Paragraph instead using new Paragraph object

Comment: yes..But with single paragraph its not possible to align the image to right side..

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to do it.

1. You can use a table to make the paragraph and image appear on the same line.
2. Use `setAbsolutePosition` on your image to set an exact position, e.g. 
   `myimg.setAbsolutePosition(400f,400f);`. That will set the position of the image wherever you want and then you can set the text to be on the same line.